# Application Note style

Tags: templates, styles

I am trying to set-up an application note style, and this is what I have come up so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{Chivo}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows, babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, textcomp}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.6\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\logosmall}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\claim}{©YYYY Company name, Inc. All rights reserved.\\ Trademarks and registered trademarks are the\\\vspace{-6pt} property of their respective owners.}
\newcommand{\website}{www.companysite.com}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revision}[1]{\gdef\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\gdef\@code{#1}}
\newcommand*{\type}[1]{\gdef\@type{#1}}
%
%
% First page
%
\fancypagestyle{first}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\logo}
    \fancyhead[R]{%
    \huge{\bf{%
    \@code\\
    \@type
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    \headrule
    %
    \fancyfoot[L]{\@date}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\@revision}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}
}
%
% Document body
\fancypagestyle{body}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    %
    \fancyfoot[L]{\@date}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\@revision}
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}
}
%
%
% Last page
\fancypagestyle{last}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    %
    \fancyfoot[L]{\vspace*{-10pt}{\tiny \claim}\\ \@date}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{-20pt}\logosmall\\ \@revision}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
    \large{
    \vspace*{10pt}
    \textbf{\website}
    \vspace*{-5pt}
    }}}\\
    Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}
    }
}
\makeatother

% custom title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{first}
\twocolumn[
\let\clearpage\relax% Remove \clearpage functionality
\vspace*{-10pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
    \bf{
        {\LARGE\@title\par}
        \@author
        }
    \end{center}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace*{30pt}
    ]
}%
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\title{My Outstanding Application Note Title}
\author{J.~Doe}
\date{22.02.2019}
\revision{Rev.~0.1}
\code{AN-1}
\type{APPLICATION~NOTE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{body}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[5]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[8]

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagestyle{last}
\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{table}[!ht]%
\caption{Revision history.}
\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
\hline
Revision & Author & Changes\\
\hline
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{onecolumn}

\end{document}
```

This mostly replicates Analog Devices application notes that I like very much (hoping I am not infringing any copyright though).

However, this is not still what I want to achieve since I can't get the index on the second page (even though it is still fine to have it on the first which is something that I like the same), I can't get company info just above the rule in the first page and footers on the last page are not properly aligned. Last, I am not a very good latex programmer so I think everything could be better arranged (maybe in a class/style).

I want to share my code and ask somebody to improve it, if possible.

Thank you.

**EDIT1:**
I come up with the following intermediate step

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{Chivo}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tipa} % for the pipe symbol
\usepackage[left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, textcomp}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\logosmall}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\claim}{©YYYY Company name, Inc. All rights reserved. Trademarks and registered trademarks are the property of their respective owners.}
\newcommand{\website}{www.companysite.com}
\newcommand{\telephone}{123.456.7890}
\newcommand{\address}{\small{One Technology Way}\large{$\cdot$}\small{P.O.Box 9106}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Norwood,MA02062-9106,USA}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revision}[1]{\gdef\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\gdef\@code{#1}}
\newcommand*{\type}[1]{\gdef\@type{#1}}
\newcommand*{\theCompany}{\textbf{{\address}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Tel:\telephone}\large{$\cdot$}\small{\website}}}
%
%
% First page
%
\fancypagestyle{first}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{94pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.27\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}} % still having some alignment issues here
    \multirow{2}{1in}{\logo}    & &                    \\
                                & &                    \\
                                & & \huge{\bf{\@code}} \\
                                & & \huge{\bf{\@type}} \\
                                & &                    \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\theCompany}                    \\
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace*{-15pt}
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    & \footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
%
% Document body
\fancypagestyle{body}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    %
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
    & \footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
%
%
% Last page
\fancypagestyle{last}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
                        & \multirow{2}{1in}{\logosmall} & \\
    \footnotesize{\claim} &                               & \multirow{2}{1in}{\fbox{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{\centering\large{\vspace*{10pt}\textbf{\website}\vspace*{5pt}}}}}\\
                        &                               & \\
                        &\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}&\\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
\makeatother

% custom title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{first}
\twocolumn[
\vspace*{-20pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
    \bf{
        {\LARGE\@title\par}
        \@author
        }
    \end{center}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace*{20pt}
    ]
}%
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\title{My Application Note Title}
\author{J.~Doe}
\date{22.02.2019}
\revision{Rev.~0.1}
\code{AN-1}
\type{APPLICATION~NOTE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{body}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[5]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[8]

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagestyle{last}
\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{table}[!ht]%
\caption{Revision history.}
\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
\hline
Revision & Author & Changes\\
\hline
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{onecolumn}

\end{document}
```

Now in the last page footer I have put a tabular environment with multirows which is replicated throughout the document body. I will try to tweak the vertical alignment so as to achieve consistents footers on everypage.

Regarding the titlepage I have used the same environment (tabular + multirow) to get proper alignment, and I have managed to get the company address stright above the horizontal rule (thanks to @derBender). However there are still some alignment issues.

The "template" needs some further work however.

**EDIT2:**

With some fine tuning I came up with this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{Chivo}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tipa} % for the pipe symbol
\usepackage[left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, textcomp}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\logosmall}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\claim}{©YYYY Company name, Inc. All rights reserved. Trademarks and registered trademarks are the property of their respective owners.}
\newcommand{\website}{www.companysite.com}
\newcommand{\websitelast}{\fbox{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{\centering\large{\vspace*{10pt}\textbf{\website}\vspace*{10pt}}}}}
\newcommand{\telephone}{123.456.7890}
\newcommand{\address}{\small{One Technology Way}\large{$\cdot$}\small{P.O.Box 9106}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Norwood,MA02062-9106,USA}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revision}[1]{\gdef\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\gdef\@code{#1}}
\newcommand*{\type}[1]{\gdef\@type{#1}}
\newcommand*{\theCompany}{\textbf{{\address}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Tel:\telephone}\large{$\cdot$}\small{\website}}}
%
% First page
%
\fancypagestyle{first}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{94pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr} % still having some alignment issues here
    \multirow{2}{1in}{\logo}    & &                    \\
                                & &                    \\
                                & & \huge{\bf{\@code}} \\
                                & & \huge{\bf{\@type}} \\
                                & &                    \\
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\theCompany}                    \\
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace*{-15pt}
    }
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr}
    & \footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
%
% Document body
\fancypagestyle{body}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength\footskip{73pt}
    %
\fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr}
        &                                                                         & \\
        &                                                                         & \\
        &                                                                         & \\
        & \footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
}
}
%
% Last page
\fancypagestyle{last}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength\footskip{73pt}
    %\multirow[<vpos>]{<nrows>}[<bigstruts>]{<width>}[<vmove>]{<text>}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
                        & \multirow[]{2}*[0.1in]{\logosmall} & \\
    \footnotesize{\claim} &                               & \multirow{2}*{\websitelast} \\
                        &                               & \\
                        &\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
\makeatother

% custom title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{first}
\twocolumn[
\vspace*{-20pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
    \bf{
        {\LARGE\@title\par}
        \@author
        }
    \end{center}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace*{20pt}
    ]
}%
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\title{My Outstanding Application Note Title}
\author{J.~Doe}
\date{22.02.2019}
\revision{Rev.~0.1}
\code{AN-1}
\type{APPLICATION~NOTE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{body}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[5]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[8]

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagestyle{last}
\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{table}[!ht]%
\caption{Revision history.}
\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
\hline
Revision & Author & Changes\\
\hline
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{onecolumn}

\end{document}
```

However the index is still sourrounded by the body text.

**EDIT3:**
Following my final version I am happy with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tipa} % for the pipe symbol
\usepackage[left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, textcomp}


\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[draft,width=0.7\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\logosmall}{\includegraphics[draft,width=0.2\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\claim}[1]{\gdef\@claim{#1}}
\newcommand{\site}[1]{\gdef\@site{#1}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revision}[1]{\gdef\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand*{\id}[1]{\gdef\@id{#1}}
\newcommand*{\type}[1]{\gdef\@type{#1}}
\newcommand*{\info}[1]{\gdef\@info{#1}}
%
% First page
%p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}
\fancypagestyle{first}{
    %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{94pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr} % still having some alignment issues here
    \multirow{2}*[-0.1in]{\logo} & &                                   \\
                                & & \huge{\textbf{\textsf{\@id}}}     \\
                                & & \huge{\textbf{\textsf{\@type}}}   \\
    \multicolumn{3}{b{0.95\textwidth}}{\footnotesize{\textsf{\@info}}} \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \vspace*{-5pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    %\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr}
    & \textsf{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
%
% Document body
\fancypagestyle{body}{
    %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\textsf{\@id}}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\textsf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\textsf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}}
    \hfill \textbf{\textsf{\@id}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength\footskip{73pt}
    %
\fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{lcr}
        &                                                                         & \\
        &                                                                         & \\
        &                                                                         & \\
        & \textsf{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
}
}
%
% Last page
\fancypagestyle{last}{
    %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\textsf{\@id}}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\textsf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\textsf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}}
    \hfill \textbf{\textsf{\@id}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength\footskip{73pt}
    %\multirow[<vpos>]{<nrows>}[<bigstruts>]{<width>}[<vmove>]{<text>}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
    \begin{tabular}[b]{p{0.4\linewidth}p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.4\linewidth}}
                        & \multirow[]{2}*[-0.15in]{\logosmall} & \\
    \textsf{\footnotesize{\@claim}} &                               & \multirow[]{2}*[0.1in]{\fbox{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{\centering\large{\vspace*{10pt}\textbf{\textsf{\@site}}\vspace*{10pt}}}}} \\
                        &                               & \\
                        &\textsf{\footnotesize{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}} & \\
    \end{tabular}
    }
}
\makeatother

% custom title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{first}
\twocolumn[
\vspace*{-20pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
        {\LARGE\textbf{\textsf{\@title}}\par}
        \textbf{\textsf{\@author}}
    \end{center}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace*{20pt}
    ]
}%
%
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\sffamily}

\title{My Outstanding Application Note Title}
\author{J.~Doe}
\date{22.02.2019}
\revision{Rev.~0.1}
\id{AN-1}
\type{APPLICATION~NOTE}
\info{Please place here company infos.}
\claim{Please, place here your copyright notice.}
\site{www.companysite.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{body}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[5]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[6]

\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\lipsum[7]

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagestyle{last}
\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{table}[!ht]%
\caption{Revision history.}
\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
\hline
Revision & Author & Changes\\
\hline
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{onecolumn}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Came up with something quite decent i think… it still can be improved though

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{Chivo}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{tipa} % for the pipe symbol
\usepackage[left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes, arrows, babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, textcomp}
\everymath{\displaystyle}


\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./img/}}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% custom header/footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[natwidth=100px,natheight=100px,width=0.6\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\logosmall}{\includegraphics[natwidth=100px,natheight=100px,width=0.2\columnwidth]{logo.png}}
\newcommand{\claim}{©YYYY Company name, Inc. All rights reserved.\\ Trademarks and registered trademarks are the\\\vspace{-6pt} property of their respective owners.}
\newcommand{\website}{www.companysite.com}
\newcommand{\telephone}{123.456.7890}
\newcommand{\address}{\small{One Technology Way}\large{$\cdot$}\small{P.O.Box 9106}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Norwood,MA02062-9106,USA}}
\renewcommand{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}
\newcommand*{\revision}[1]{\gdef\@revision{#1}}
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\gdef\@code{#1}}
\newcommand*{\type}[1]{\gdef\@type{#1}}
\newcommand*{\theCompany}{\textbf{{\address}\large{$\cdot$}\small{Tel:\telephone}\large{$\cdot$}\small{\website}}}
%
%
% First page
%
\fancypagestyle{first}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\logo\\}
    \fancyhead[R]{
                    \huge{
                        \bf{
                            \@code\\
                            \@type\\
                           }
                    }
                 }
    \fancyhead[C]{~\\~\\\theCompany}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
    %
    %\vspace*{-30pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\tiny{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
}
%
% Document body
\fancypagestyle{body}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    %
    \fancyfoot[C]{\tiny{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
}
%
%
% Last page
\fancypagestyle{last}{
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \setlength\headheight{47pt}
    %\renewcommand{\topmargin}{0pt}
    % even pages
    \fancyhead[CE]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\@code}
    \hfill
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    % odd pages
    \fancyhead[CO]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{
    \vspace*{10pt}\huge{
    \textbf{\color{lightgray}{\@type}}
    \hfill \textbf{\@code}
    }
    \vspace*{10pt}
    }}}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

    \fancyfoot[L]{\vspace*{-10pt}{\tiny \claim}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace{-60pt}\hspace{1cm}\logosmall\\\tiny{\@revision\textpipe{}Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\fbox{%
    \parbox{0.3\textwidth}{
    \centering
    \large{
    \vspace*{10pt}
    \textbf{\website}
    \vspace*{5pt}
    }}}\\
    ~
    }
}
\makeatother

% custom title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\thispagestyle{first}
\twocolumn[
%\let\clearpage\relax% Remove \clearpage functionality
\vspace*{-10pt}% Insert needed vertical retraction
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \begin{center}
    \bf{
        {~\par}
        ~
        }
    \end{center}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    \vspace*{90pt}
    ]
}%
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % sections are level 1

\title{}
\author{}
\date{22.02.2019}
\revision{Rev.~0.1}
\code{AN-1}
\type{APPLICATION~NOTE}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{center}
        %\title
        %\author{J.~Doe}
        \renewcommand{\title}{My Application Note Title}
        \renewcommand{\author}{J.~Doe}
        \Large{\textbf{\title \\ by \author}}
    \end{center}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[1]
\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{body}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Section}
\lipsum[4]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[5]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Paragraph}
\lipsum[8]

\newpage
\clearpage
\pagestyle{last}
\begin{onecolumn}
\begin{table}[!ht]%
\caption{Revision history.}
\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}p{0.3\linewidth}}
\hline
Revision & Author & Changes\\
\hline
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{onecolumn}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

known Problems are:

-title not centered above both columns

-toc not on seperate page

-footer on final page not quite aligned (Maybe some hspaces and vspaces can help here?)

Comment: improved footer alignment on last page (didnt Change the Pictures though). Code is already edited

Comment: Very nice! I haven't had the time to work on mine. I think the title should be centered and the toc should be one column. But we are almost done. I will try to modify it further today. Thank you @DerBender.

Comment: @ve3m You can show appreciation for the work of others by up-voting their answers.

Comment: +1: Looks pretty familiar :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you for pointing that. I voted but is says that votes from those who have reputation below 15 are recoded but they don't increment the answer score.

Comment: @ve3m Ok, I see. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I would like to add a rendered preview of the latex code. How can I upload pdfs and link them to the post the way der bender did?

Comment: @ve3m They are pixel images, not PDF. If you edit your question, then you should see a button for that. Maybe you need more reputation in order to do so. I am offline for now and cannot assist more at this point.

Comment: one Thing to Point out: as a blueprint/example of what we want to replicate here i used AN-1057 from the Analog devices Website... I figured out that they are NOT using the A4 paper standart as we do here. therefor some tweaks with the margins had to be made and who ever reads this must be Aware that exact replication may or may not be possible (with this format)

Comment: @derbender Ohhh, good point! Thank you. However I think that what we have come up so far (see EDIT3) can be acceptable. My aim was to achieve something who could look professional as much as possible. And I think we succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `\tableofcontents` after (instead of before) the `\clearpages` did the trick for me.

In addition, here are some minor suggestions: At first I had problems when compiling your MWE because LaTeX was not able to figure out the dimensions of the `logo.png` (and I know that it can not even if the file were present) so what I usually do in these cases is adding a `natheight=100px, natwidth=100px` (or any other number, check that in your files) to the `\includegraphics`

**Edits:** I figured that to make it look a bit more like an appnote from AD, the footer needs to be done a bit different: there is no date in the footer (so I ommitted that line) and the "Page x of y" is centered but seperated from the revision number by a "|" (archived by `\usepackage{tipa}` and `\textpipe` also the textsize is very small so I enclosed the text in the footer with a `{\tiny…}`

Temporarily I came up with the following logo (size 100 px * 100 px):

[image]

Comment: the title page is quite empty then though. if i remind the analog devices application notestyle right then there is still a long way to go...

Comment: By moving \tableofcontents after (instead of before) the \clearpages then I can't get the body text on the title page however. Which is what @der says, I guess. The template should allow to have the body text on the title page, following the index (which usually span just one page, i.e. the second) and then the rest of the body on the third page and following. Regarding the logo, I get compilation errors when I use natheight=100px, natwidth=100px. I am going to work it to improve the code however.

Comment: the numbers are only illustrational and MUST be matched to your Image size. and they belong into the [] of the \includegraphics just in case you did not understand that this way. Looking into if i can get anything on the first page. first try would be to ommit the \clearpage completely

Comment: I got compilation errors sayng that natheight and natwidth were unreckognized. However now they work.